# Is there a closed form for an integral $\int \{\frac{1}{x}\} dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, special-functions

Is there a closed form for an integral: $$\int \left\{\frac{1}{x}\right\} dx$$

I know $\int_0^1 \left\{\frac{1}{x}\right\} dx=1-\gamma$

Comment: You could write the indefinite integral in terms of a definite one: $$ -\int_x^1 \{1/t\}{\rm d}t+C. $$

Answer (score 1):

Use the same idea:

Split up $ \{ 1 / x \} = 1/x - \lfloor 1/x \rfloor $, and then integrate on regions $ [ 1/(n+1), 1/n]$.

Comment: I see how to split over $[0,1]$. https://brilliant.org/wiki/fractional-part-function/  How can we split when the limits of integration are not given?

Comment: @mathisgood Find the integral from $ a$ to $b$, then see if you have a closed form for it, meaning you can convert it to $ [ f(x) ]^a_b$.  It will likely involve $ \lfloor  1/ a \rfloor$. If you're stuck, show  your work.